# MysqlDump does not exporting Data when is called from a '".bat"' file

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am currently exporting some data with mysqldump and **--where** param i.e:

`mysqldump -u root  databasename tablename --where="datefield > '2003-10-29 00:00:00' AND show=1" > dumpresult.sql`.

When i execute the command in cmd works perfect (exports structure and data) but if i put it in a batch file (.bat) only exports structure WITHOUT data.

Somebody knows what can be happening here?

i tried to changing .bat to .cmd, executed as administrator, etc.

Comment: if he exports well the table structure and not the data, this means that WHERE condition is returning false (not met your condition).

Comment: but when i execute the same command (copy and paste) in CMD works great. The issue is when use it in a bat file.

Comment: try add in your ".bat" file.  "echo on" and "echo mysqldump -u root  databasename tablename --where="datefield > '2003-10-29 00:00:00' AND show=1" > dumpresult.sql" to  see what is really passed.

Comment: @AdelinoSilva Thanks again, if i use "echo on" nothing changes. Actually i think it is set to "on" by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the issue. When using batch file (.bat) some symbols (%) that preceed some word are interpreted as enviroment variables so i must to put double %% percent symbol. This does not ocurr when use de complete command directly in CMD.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).